# How do I list all the functions in the math module?

Tags: python

Is there a way to find out what all the functions in the math module are? I'm not sure how to find this out. I have tried searching it up but it just directly tells me what they are rather than a built in help

Comment: `import math; help(math)`?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you don't just want to see what functions are available, you want some help on each of them too? It isn't obvious from your question at all.

Comment: You could also look at python.org

Comment: `import math;dir(math)`?

Answer (score 4):

```
import math
for method in dir(math):
    print method
```

Output:

```
__doc__
__name__
__package__
acos
acosh
asin
asinh
atan
atan2
atanh
ceil
copysign
cos
cosh
degrees
e
erf
erfc
exp
expm1
fabs
factorial
floor
fmod
frexp
fsum
gamma
hypot
isinf
isnan
ldexp
lgamma
log
log10
log1p
modf
pi
pow
radians
sin
sinh
sqrt
tan
tanh
trunc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the dir() method to find all the functions in a module.
First import the module.